# Posting to twitter API using nextjs, posting tweets while website is not being requested

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, twitter-api-v2

Current state: I'm currently using next.js to build a web app. I would like this web app to also post to my Twitter account. I've already created a developer account on Twitter and an API in nextjs. Calling the api will trigger the post request, and it will create a post on my Twitter account since all the authentication is set up.

What I would like:
I would like my account to post a tweet every 24 hours, so let's say every day at 5 in the morning (my local time). I would need this tweet to be posted, also when nobody is requesting the website. Unfortunately, I didn't figure out how to set this up yet. Any help is appreciated.

I've been thinking about using getStaticProps with the revalidate function from nextjs but I realized that when nobody is requesting the webpage it still won't work. Even when the code is executed server-side.

This is what the code in my API currently looks like:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import Twitter from 'twitter'

export default async function postTweet(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse){
   
    const client = new Twitter({
        consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY ?? "",
        consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET ?? "",
        access_token_key: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY ?? "",
        access_token_secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET ?? "",
      });
      
      client.post(
        'statuses/update',
        { status: message + `(${currentDate})` },
        function (error, tweet, response) {
          if (error) throw error;
        //   console.log(tweet); // Tweet body.
        //   console.log(response); // Raw response object.
        }
      );

}
```

Any ideas of how I could realize this are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's really good question.
You can achieve this by setting a `CRON JOB`. It's a way to tell server to run a specific task with an time interval or at a specific time of a day/week/month etc.

If you want to use GitHub Actions, it has a CRON JOB feature
you can read more here https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/solutions/cron-jobs
You can generate cron expression https://crontab.cronhub.io/
as eg: for everyday at 5AM : `0 5 * * *`

```
name: tweet-at-morning
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 5 * * *'
jobs:
  cron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Call our API route
        run: |
          curl --request POST \
          --url 'https://yoursite.com/api/cron' \
          --header 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.API_SECRET_KEY }}'
```

Otherwise, you can use a node library to make a job queue.
I found Bull.js https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull this library as easiest and reliable one for creating job server.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! Implemented it and it's working like a charm.